# Adding Integer getting User Input From console In Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

```
int main()
{
    int number1;
    int number2;

    cout<<"enter first and second number";

    cin>>number1,number2;

    int sum=number1+number2;

    cout<<"sum is", sum ;
}
```

I'm using Objective-C online editior. My question is how to get user input from console? Is it possible to convert this program into Objective-C syntax?

Comment: The code you posted is C++ code, not Objective-C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Objective-**C** you can use the C stdio functions to get input from `stdin`, and write to `stdout`. You must be aware that C strings and Objective-C/Cocoa’s `NSString` are different, so if you read in strings you will probably need to convert them – see the `NSString` documentation.

If your "online editor" supports Objective-**C++** then you can use the C++ stream IO functions as in your sample code.